# How can I show the PHP results of a contact form with AJAX?

Tags: php, html, ajax, load

I have a simple html contact form, and the php script to send the emails. It's working good, but I want the result (The email has been sent...) to show in the same page, without changing the page. How can I do this?

HTML:

```
<form name="contact" action="includes/send.php" id="contact_form">

    <input type="text" placeholder="Name" name="name" /> <br />

    <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" /> <br />

    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="8"></textarea> <br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Send" /> 

</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$to = 'amar123syla@gmail.com';
$subject = 'Message from AMARSYLA.COM';
$message = 'FROM: '.$name.' Email: '.$email.'Message: '.$message;
$headers = 'From: amar123syla@gmail.com';

if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) { // this line checks that we have a valid email address
    mail($to, $subject, $message) or die('Error sending Mail'); //This method sends the mail.
    echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}

?>
```

Comment: You appear to be asking for an Ajax 101 tutorial. That isn't the sort of question that is appropriate for Stackoverflow. Try a search engine instead (which could get you results such as [this mdn resource](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest)).

Comment: If you only want to do that, you dont have to use ajax, unless you dont want page to refresh while submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.post('email.php', score, function(result) {
    jQuery('#textBlock').html(result);
});
```

Something like that should work(Result is the echo in your php in this case)

A preffered method is to encode your php result to json so you've got a little more control over it in Javascript though.

```
jQuery.post('email.php', score, function(result) {
    if (result.result == true) {
        jQuery('#textBlock').html(result.text);
    }
});
```

And in the email.php:

```
$result['result'] = true;
$result['text'] = 'Message has been sent';

header('Content-Type: application/json');
echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score -2):

Here see if this works:

```
<form name="contact" action="**submit to same page**" id="contact_form">



<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Send" /> 

</form>
```

Then for the php (on the same page as the email form) just add if submit

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

 run your email script, add javascript, etc.
echo "Your email was sent!"; // success message
}


  }
    ?>
```